# Nesting multiple CMSRepeaters in Kentico

Tags: kendo-ui, kentico

My CMSRepeater:

```
<cms:CMSRepeater runat="server" ID="RptMainNav" Path="/menu/%" ClassNames="KP.Home" MaxRelativeLevel="1" OnItemDataBound="RptMainNav_ItemDataBound1" NestedControlsID="RptSubMainNav" OrderBy="NodeOrder,NodeLevel">
<ItemTemplate>
    <li class="navbar-menu-accordion">
        <a href='<%# Eval("URL") %>'><%# Eval("Name") %></a>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HfRpt" Value='<%# Eval("NodeAliasPath") %>' />
        <i class="show-for-small hide-for-large fa fa-angle-down search-icon angle-icon"></i>
        <cms:CMSRepeater runat="server" ID="RptSubMainNav" DelayedLoading="true" StopProcessing="true" OrderBy="NodeOrder,NodeLevel" MaxRelativeLevel="1">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul class="menu below-box-menu">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <li class="below-box-menu-links"><a href='<%# Eval("URL") %>'><%# Eval("Name") %></a>

                </li>

            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </ul>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </cms:CMSRepeater>
    </li>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and code behind

```
protected void RptMainNav_ItemDataBound1(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater RptSubMainNav = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("RptSubMainNav");
        HiddenField HfValue = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HfRpt");



        string GetNode = HfValue.Value;

        DataSet child = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("KP.Home").Path(GetNode, PathTypeEnum.Children);

      // DataSet d=  DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("KP.Home").Path(DocumentContext.CurrentDocument.NodeAliasPath, PathTypeEnum.Children);

        RptSubMainNav.DataSource = child;
        RptSubMainNav.DataBind();




    }
}
```

i am getting only one node elements

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code you wrote is from ASCX transformation, you can use nested control in that using approach mentioned in [this](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/references/kentico-controls/cms-controls/cms-controls-listings-and-viewers/using-nested-controls) article.

However, please do keep in mind that nesting listing controls such as repeater will have negative impact on the performance and is generally considered as bad practice because you will be executing:

No rows * number of nested repeaters + 1

SQL queries. It is therefore highly recommended to at least cache the result.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use Hierarchical Viewers instead of nested repeaters as, like Enn mentioned, nested repeaters are performance hit.

[Here](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/using-hierarchical-transformations) is some documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you created custom web part for this? If yes, then it looks to me like everything is OK with your code, maybe to check DataSet child, just to be sure if there is more than one element. Also, good approach is to define asp elements inside .ascx, and then populate them with values from code behind, f.e.:

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="TextValueID" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

You can define event ItemDataBound for nested repeater also, and populate it there.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in content tree which means already hierarchical structure then you should opt for hierarchical viewer instead of nested repeater

https://docs.kentico.com/k9/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/using-hierarchical-transformations